# How do I initialize a property before use in a ionic and ion-selectable filter service?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

I have a service that can use manually entered data in an array and everything works fine.  However when I retrieve data from a database, the public geemployee: GElist[] runs before finishing retrieving the data.  If I bring the data retrieval into the same service I receive the Error Property 'databaseModelEmployees' is used before its initialization.  How can I initialize this data before use?

ts

```
import { Contractor } from '../../types';
import { FindingCat } from '../../types';
import { GElist } from '../../types';
import { DatabaseModelService } from './database-model.service';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Injectable()
export class EmployeeService {
  databaseModelEmployees: any;
  public contractors: Contractor[] = this.databaseModelService.databaseModel[0].Contractor;
  public findingcat: FindingCat[] = this.databaseModelService.databaseModel[1].FindingCat;
  public geemployee: GElist[] = this.databaseModelService.databaseModelEmployees; // runs before the data is retrieved
  public geemployee2: GElist[] = this.databaseModelEmployees;  // failProperty 'databaseModelEmployees' is used before its initialization.

  constructor( 
    private databaseModelService: DatabaseModelService, 
    public storage: Storage ) { 
      this.getData();
  }

  getData() {
    this.storage.get("favEmployees").then((employees) => { 
      let employeeList = JSON.parse(employees)
      this.databaseModelEmployees = employeeList;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the answer was a lot simpler than I though.  I moved the equals into the storage.get

ts

```
  import { Injectable} from '@angular/core';
  import { Contractor } from '../../types';
  import { FindingCat } from '../../types';
  import { GElist } from '../../types';
  import { DatabaseModelService } from './database-model.service';
  import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

  @Injectable()
  export class EmployeeService {
    public contractors: Contractor[] = this.databaseModelService.databaseModel[0].Contractor;
    public findingcat: FindingCat[] = this.databaseModelService.databaseModel[1].FindingCat;
    public geemployee: GElist[];
    databaseEmployees: any;

    constructor( private databaseModelService: DatabaseModelService, public storage: Storage ) {
      this.getEmployee();
    }

    getEmployee() {
      this.storage.get("favEmployees").then((employees) => { 
        let empList = JSON.parse(employees)
        this.databaseEmployees = [ { ID: 1, Name: "Employees", list:  empList} ];
        this.geemployee = this.databaseEmployees;
        console.log("this.geemployee",this.geemployee);
      });
    }
}
```